# Abrir nueva pestaña al hacer click derecho en una fila angular

Tags: c#, angular, eventos, aplicación-web, ts

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de [angular] y typescript y tengo un componente común llamado *tabla* cuyas filas están definidas de la siguiente forma:

`<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event, row)"></tr>`

Me han pedido que capture el evento del clic derecho y que al hacerlo, abra una pestaña nueva con el contenido de la fila que he clicado.

¿Alguna idea de como abrir la pestaña nueva?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar lo siguiente

```
onRightClick(event: MouseEvent, fila: any) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Evita el menú contextual del navegador
  const nuevaPestana = window.open('', '_blank'); // Abre una nueva pestaña
  nuevaPestana.document.write(`
  <html><head><title>Contenido de la fila</title> 
  </head><body>${fila}</body></html>`);
}
```